# How to get days missed in attendance table in mysql using NOT IN

Tags: mysql

I have a database for taking attendance daily.
every day is accounted for in a datetime *(attended)* field since there are never no students.
So, for a particular student ID *(sid)* I figure I'd be able to fill in the gaps of attendance using NOT IN.

```
select arrived, date_format(arrived,'%a') as 'day' 
from attendance 
where sid = '38'
  and date_format(arrived, '%Y-%m-%d') NOT IN (
    select DISTINCT date_format(arrived, '%Y-%m-%d') 
    from attendance 
    where MONTH(arrived) = 6
  ) 
  and MONTH(arrived) = 6
```

However, this generates the same results as if I hadn't used NOT IN at all.  Now I'm realizing that those missing dates can't print because they're not in the *sid* limited query to begin with.
Can I move the NOT IN to the front of the query, so that the actual dates I want to display as absent are displayable.
For example, the student was absent 2019-06-06 (since that date is missing in 'his' query and other students were (so the nested query *does* show 2019-06-06)

Comment: You would  have to join with a table that contains all the dates of interest, either pre-defined or using distinct on your attendance table.

Comment: Here is a quick fiddle to show a query that may work: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d899e1151e9718506cd8cd589cc0d1d). I just used integer values because it is quicker to prototype without sample data.

Comment: Swap the inner and outer queries.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x8VVvMBmizmsbJRHmY1GEd/0

```
select date(absences) absences from (select distinct date(arrived) absences from attendance) t2
where date(t2.absences) not in (select date(arrived) from attendance where sid=38)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the inner and the outer query. You should look for attendance days of all students that are NOT IN attendance days of the specific student (sid=38):

```
select DISTINCT date(arrived) as 'day' 
from attendance 
where date(arrived) NOT IN (
    select date(arrived) 
    from attendance 
    where sid = '38'
      and MONTH(arrived) = 6
  ) 
  and MONTH(arrived) = 6
```